# How to get all images afer tag <imgs>, to . | xslt

Tags: xslt

XML `1.0`
encoding: `UTF-8`

Output data:

```
<name>
Test Product Name
</name>
<imgs>
<image>
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077.jpg
</image>
<image>
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,1.jpg
</image>
<image>
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,2.jpg
</image>
</imgs>
<description>
Here is product description
</description>
```

`images` is afer tag `<imgs>`

XSLT

```
 <xsl:element name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="imgs">
              <xsl:value-of select="imgs"/>
           </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="description">
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            </xsl:element>
```

result:

```
<imgs>
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077.jpg
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,1.jpg
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,2.jpg
</imgs>
```

**Descirption issue:**
currently I cannot run import because script read this as one long url image.

To solve, Expected Result:

```
<imgs>
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077.jpg,
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,1.jpg,
https://websiteimport.com/_data/products/sku-11077sku-11077,2.jpg,
</imgs>
```

How to add `,` after each image?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. Also, in all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: I intentionally show code before and after this tag -  to show behind the picture are just behind the <imgs> tag and other things not - because that makes the solution difficult. If everything was for this <imgs> I would solve it myself with the match function

Comment: You intentionally make it difficult for us to reproduce your problem and to test the proposed solution.

Comment: Forgive me Michael. I wanted to show it as best as possible on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I an guessing you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
<imgs>
    <xsl:for-each select="imgs/image">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>,&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</imgs>
<xsl:copy-of select="description"/>
```

Comment: this is what we wanted to achieve. Thanks!